# Windows equivalent to this Makefile

Tags: python, windows, cross-platform, makefile

The advantage of writing a Makefile is that "make" is generally assumed to be present on the various Unices (Linux and Mac primarily).

Now I have the following Makefile:

```
PYTHON := python

all: e installdeps

e:
        virtualenv --distribute --python=${PYTHON} e

installdeps:
        e/bin/python setup.py develop
        e/bin/pip install unittest2

test:   
        e/bin/unit2 discover

clean:  
        rm -rf e
```

As you can see this Makefile uses simple targets and variable substitution. Can this be achieved on Windows? By that mean - without having to install external tools (like cygwin make); perhaps make.cmd? Typing "make installdeps" for instance, should work both on Unix and Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Something simple like that, yes.  However, if you'd like to continue to improve that makefile, you might consider just writing the "makefile" (rather installation script) in a more portable language.  You have to have some assumptions.  If its a python project, I'm sure you assume python is installed.  So write the equivalent of your makefile in python.

Comment: Along those lines, you might want to look into Scons, which is a build system coded in Python.

Comment: good point, but it is an extra package to install.  At least with a python project, you can assume that python is installed, it might be too much to assume that scons is installed, even though it is written in python.

Comment: Scons is some of the most hideous Python code I have ever seen.

Comment: @fuzzy good to know, maybe I won't spend time looking into it then someday

Comment: Nomenclature wise I wince when someone says "makefile" meaning a script written in a language *other* than make. May I suggest 'Write your "installation script" in python.'? Very good suggestion, though.

Comment: @dmckee good point, your "Write your 'installation script'" is definitely what I meant without saying it.